# How can I hire a bunch of aliens quickly?

Tags: startopia

When I've just created a new building, I usually want to hire a half-dozen aliens at a time. Unfortunately, the only way I've found to hire aliens is to go to the management screen, find the visitors, and select one. This closes the management screen and highlights the single alien, who has a button I can click to hire them. Repeating this sequence (management->zoom to alien->hire) is vexing when I want to do it a half-dozen times in a row.

Is there a faster way to hire alien visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

There's no way to expedite the hiring process. However, if a peep is busy in a building (most often asleep) when you fly to them, you can eject them from the building by clicking the character's icon in the building's menu.